# Sprite Kit: Getting the absolute node position

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

How can I get the absolute position of the _childNode in this example:

I have a parent:
_worldNode

I have a child:
_childNode

I set the _childNode position to 10,10.

I rotate _worldNode 90 degrees.

Now, when I query the _childNode position I am given 10,10. Naturally this is no longer the case. Even doing [_childNode calculateAccumulatedFrame] gives me a CGRect at 10,10.

Any ideas how to return the correct position (-10,10)?
Here's the code from my test (just put into init, all logs return 10,10).

```
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
    CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;
    CGPoint screenCentre = CGPointMake(screenHeight/2.0,screenWidth/2.0);

    _worldNode = [SKNode node];
    _worldNode.position = screenCentre;
    [self addChild:_worldNode];


    _childNode = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithColor:[UIColor redColor] size:CGSizeMake(10, 10)];
    _childNode.position = CGPointMake(10, 10);
    [_worldNode addChild:_childNode];

    NSLog(@"position of child pre rotation %f, %f", _childNode.position.x, _childNode.position.y);

    _worldNode.zRotation = 90;

    NSLog(@"position of child after rotation %f, %f", _childNode.position.x, _childNode.position.y);

    CGPoint position = _childNode.position;
    [_childNode convertPoint:position toNode:_worldNode];

    NSLog(@"position of child after conversion %f, %f", position.x, position.y);

    CGRect groupRect = [_childNode calculateAccumulatedFrame];

    CGPoint newPosition = CGPointMake(groupRect.origin.x + (groupRect.size.width / 2), groupRect.origin.y + (groupRect.size.height / 2));
    NSLog(@"position of child based on frame %f, %f",newPosition.x,newPosition.y);
```

Many thanks in advance,
Ian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of mistakes in your code.

**1-**

```
_worldNode.position = screenCentre;  //This places the node at the SKScene centre
```

should be

```
_worldNode.position = CGPointZero; //This places the node at the origin.
```

The SKScene's default coordinate system has the origin at the lower left corner.

**2-**

```
_worldNode.zRotation = 90;
```

should be

```
_worldNode.zRotation = M_PI_2;
```

The zRotation is measured in radians, not degrees.

**3-**

Look at the two NSLogs in the code:

```
NSLog(@"position of child after rotation %f, %f", _childNode.position.x, _childNode.position.y); // - 1

CGPoint position = _childNode.position;
[_childNode convertPoint:position toNode:_worldNode]; //returns a CGPoint, where are you storing it?

NSLog(@"position of child after conversion %f, %f", position.x, position.y); // - 2
```

The `position` variable is not actually converted. The method returns another CGPoint which in turn will need to be logged.

However, this will return the wrong position as `_childNode.position` stores it's position relative to it's parent (i.e. `_worldNode`) and hence using `convertPoint` to `_worldNode` will convert (10,10) on the _childNode to _worldNode, making it (20,20).

Try using this line instead:

```
CGPoint position = [self convertPoint:_childNode.position fromNode:_worldNode];
NSLog (@"Position: %@", [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:position]);
```

This will give you the position w.r.t the Scene, which is what you were aiming at.

Comment: Many thanks! 1. Actually, that's fine for what I'm doing, though I appreciate it confuses the example I gave, sorry for that. 2. Again, quick example, silly mistake, forgot it took rads. 3. The solution works, it's a silly mistake, I assumed the point position was converted implicitly (?).

Answer (score 1):

In short: rotation doesn't change node's position.

`SKSpriteNode`'s `position` returns a position of an `anchorPoint` for that node.

When you rotate `SKSpriteNode`, it's rotating over its `anchorPoint`, so node's `anchorPoint` remains in the same position as it was before rotation. That's why you always get (10, 10)